# Align the button within paragraph tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written some inline css for the button to look like a link. The purpose of doing this is because I wanted to postback the form. The problem I am facing is with the formatting. Originally it was a href which I replaced with the button. The link is not wrapping with the text. Could somebody help. There is a lot of space before and after the button.

```
<p>
  To transact through FundsNetwork you will firstly need to login to your <input style="background-color: transparent; text-decoration: underline; border: none; white-space: normal; color: blue; cursor: pointer; "  title="Link to FundsNetwork account manager. (opens in a new window)" 
                                             type=submit  value="FundsNetwork Account Manager" >




                                                To access this you will need your 
                                                FundsNetwork Customer Reference Number (a ten digit number beginning with ‘1’ 
                                                that can found on your most recent statement from FundsNetwork) and pin. Please 
                                                call FundsNetwork on 0800 995511 if you need help logging in to the account manager.
                                       </p>
```

Comment: Setting `padding:0;` seems to fix it.

Comment: i tried it but doesnt work for me

Comment: Which browser are you testing on? Here, using latest Opera, it seems aligned.

Comment: Seems ok in chrome for me too. Can you give me an image of what`s unaligned? Or. better yet, an example in any site like jsfiddle.net

Comment: I also recommend you inspect the element using chrome's inspect (right click -> inspect element) tool to find any CSS rule that might be applying to it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried but it didnt. I used an alternative approach of using the a href tag to do the postback instead of using html submit button and that sorted my issue. Thanks for your help Andre